# Magento 2 How to Increase payment session PayUMoney

Tags: payment-methods, payment-gateway, checkoutsession

Hi Am Testing PayU Payment gateway for magento 2. I have a testing account for payUMoney.
During checkout after the adding credentials and OTP its shows error if it exceeds 30 seconds. If I add credentials and OTP within 30 seconds its getting redirected to success message page.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to PayUIndia\Payu\Model\Payu\Interceptor::postProcessing() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\DataObject, null given, called in /data/www/uat/app/code/PayUIndia/Payu/Controller/Standard/Response.php on line 25 and defined in /data/www/uat/generated/code/PayUIndia/Payu/Model/Payu/Interceptor.php:124 Stack trace: #0 /data/www/uat/app/code/PayUIndia/Payu/Controller/Standard/Response.php(25): PayUIndia\Payu\Model\Payu\Interceptor->postProcessing(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor), NULL, Array) #1 /data/www/uat/generated/code/PayUIndia/Payu/Controller/Standard/Response/Interceptor.php(24): PayUIndia\Payu\Controller\Standard\Response->execute() #2 /data/www/uat/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(108): PayUIndia\Payu\Controller\Standard\Response\Interceptor->execute() #3 /data/www/uat/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #4 /data/www/uat/ve in /data/www/uat/generated/code/PayUIndia/Payu/Model/Payu/Interceptor.php on line 124
```

I am not Understanding how to handle this. Can I get some help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you resolve this issue, am also facing the same issue on Magento 2.4.3-p1 version.

Comment: Any solution to the above issue?